# Partitioning - Does the number of consumer instances always has to match the partition count provided by producer?

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

In my Producer application.properties, I have

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.producer.partitionKeyExpression=payload
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.producer.partitionCount=4
```

And my consumer application.properties looks like this

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.partitioned=true
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.group=group01
```

When I deploy my app to Pivotal Cloud Foundry, and I scale the app to 2 instance, I see that two queues are created. They are bounded to the exchange with suffix -0 and -1.

But this means that if a message comes with topic ending with -3 or -4 then they are lost because no bindings exist for those topics. If I scale the consumer to have 4 instance, then it works as expected.

My question is is it not possible to have consumer instances less than the partitionCount of producer? In this case one or more of the queues will have multiple bindings to the exchange

Answer (score 1):

This is the case for RabbitMQ, which is not a partitioned medium by default - each partition corresponds to one instance/queue. With Kafka we do support multiple partitions per consumer (so a topic will be shared across the multiple instances of an application). We are considering supporting something similar for RabbitMQ, although the difficulty in that particular case is that it is not easy to know how many partitions are in total (except by inspecting the topic, which is error-prone).

Answer (score -1):

The no. of consumer instances need not match with the no. of partitions in the topic:

1. If the no. of consumers is lesser than the partitions, then some of the consumer instances start to fetch data from multiple partitions
2. If the no. of consumers is greater than the partitions, then some of the consumer instances will never receive any data. It will simply stay idle.

Comment: This is correct for Kafka, but incorrect for RabbitMQ, where only one partition/queue is allocated to a client.